# How can I check to see if a file descriptor was closed?

Tags: c, low-level, low-level-code, low-level-io

In a POSIX environment when using system calls to manipulate text files (`open(), close(), read(), write()`), is there a way to to check to see if I actually closed a file descriptor when using `close(file_descriptor)`?

**Example**:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int input_file; // file descriptor for input file
    int output_file; // file descriptor for output file
    input_file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY));
    ouput_file = open(argv[2], ...file properties & permissions and crap.....);

    // blah blah blah...

    close(input_file);
    close(output_file);

    // what can I code here to check if the file descriptor was actually closed?
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is probably to just check the return value of your first `close`.

```
if (close(input_file)) {
    perror("close");
} else {
    // all good
}
```

**This is the only thread-safe way.**  In a multi-threaded program, another thread could get a new file descriptor that recycles the fd number of the one that was just closed.

---

**In single-threaded code only, where nothing can recycle an fd between close and  check**:

If you wish to check whether a file descriptor is valid afterwards then you can use any function that consumes a file descriptor and check it's error code. The most non-intervening and light weight is probably `fcntl/F_GETFL`

```
if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) < 0 && errno == EBADF) {
    // file descriptor is invalid or closed
}
```

You could also just call `close` a second time and it can also fail with `EBADF`.

```
if (close(fd) && errno == EBADF) {
    // file descriptor is invalid or closed
} else {
    // we successfully closed fd *now* (e.g. first close failed with EINTR)
    // or there was a different error
}
```

`close` doesn't modify `errno` on success, but we only read `errno` when `close` returns non-zero, meaning it has been set.

Comment: @SteveJobs: Each of those methods are dangerous in a multi-threaded environment, as the file descriptor in question might very have been recycled by another thread since it has been closed the last time.

Comment: Evil assignment. It should be `errno == EBADF`.

Comment: Be careful in multi-threaded programs.  File descriptors are re-used.  Therefore closing an FD could result in another FD with the same value being opened right after the `close()` - if another thread gets in and opens another file very quickly.  The only thread-safe way to do this is to check the return value.

Comment: Yoda conditions I recommend if you are to check global variables against values. Protect from evil assignments you must. `EBADF == errno`

Comment: This answer isn't guaranteed to work.  If `close()` succeeds, it won't modify `errno`.  `errno` needs to be set to `0` prior to calling `close()`.  Checking if the file descriptor is valid afterwards also won't work for a multithreaded program, or in any other situation where the file descriptor can be reused.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: this code only reads `errno` in cases where `close` failed and returned non-zero, so there's no need to zero it first.  I did edit the error to warn about thread safety though.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the return value of `close()` and the error number accordingly.

from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/close.html

> Upon successful completion, 0 shall be returned; otherwise, -1 shall
>       be returned and *errno* set to indicate the error.
>
> [...]
>
> The *close()* function shall fail if:
>
> [EBADF]
>
> The *fildes* argument is not a valid file descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

The only save method to check whether a file descriptor is invalid is to explicitly set it to (for example) `-1` on definition and every time it successfully has been closed.

The could be done using macro:

```
#define FD_INVALID (-1)

#define FD_CLOSE_AND_INVALIDATE(fd) \
do { \
  if (-1 == close(fd)) \
  { \
    perror("close failed"); \
  } \
  else \
  { \
    (fd) = FD_INVALID; \
  } \
} while (0)

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  int input_file = FD_INVALID; /* Properly initialise file descriptor for input file */
  int output_file = FD_INVALID; /*  Properly initialise file descriptor for output file */

  input_file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY));
  ouput_file = open(argv[2], ...);

  /* Do something. */

  FD_CLOSE_AND_INVALIDATE(input_file);
  FD_CLOSE_AND_INVALIDATE(output_file);

  /* To check if the file descriptor was actually closed just test for FD_INVALID. */
}
```

Comment: If system has many file descriptors, maintain an hash map of file descriptors and each time u close, set them to -1.